# ubuntu 16.04 fresh installation without integrated graphics, problem with nvidia geforce gtx

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I have a motherboard-cpu combo *without* integrated grahics support (AMD Ryzen 3 processor does not support integrated graphics). So I have to use GPU card with installation. My GPU is NVidia chip based GeForce GTX 970.

When I'm trying to do 16.04 fresh installation from USB stick, installation starts ok. I get the prompt to install Ubuntu or try without installing. But immediately after I choose to install or try, my screen does not work any more.

I've read some instructions and they all start with "use your integrated graphics for installation", but it is not possible, since I don't have integrated graphics.

Is there a fix?

Comment: Actually all instructions recommend using the `nomodeset` parameter until the proper Nvidia graphics drivers are installed. Using integrated graphics when available is an unprofessional workaround, never a solution.

Comment: Unless your discrete GPU is dead. I have an MBP with dead ATI and this is the only way to make the machine work.

Answer (score 1):

As https://askubuntu.com/users/692175/michaelbay said, the right answer is to use    nomodeset

- hold down the shift key when booting starts.
- You will then get a console mode menu.
- Scroll to "Install Ubuntu"
- Press 'e' to edit that line.
- Move to the end of the line. Delete the text that says "quiet splash" and then enter "nomodeset" instead, ensuring there is a space between the new option and any other option.
- Press F10 to boot

After Ubuntu installation Ubuntu will reboot. Press "Esc" key to enter command propt. Choose"Ubuntu". Press "e" to edit commands and once again delete the text that says "quiet splash" and then enter "nomodeset" instead and boot by pressing F10. In Ubuntu go to the "Software and Updates" and download NVIDIA proprietary drivers.